# PHP __autoload() function not working

Tags: php

i want to use `__autoload()` but it is not working here is the code

```
   function __autoload($class)
{


require_once($class.".php");

}
```

and here create object

```
$obj =  new MyClass();
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get any errors? Does that file even exist? etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
function __autoload($class)
{

    require_once($class.".php");
}
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');

$obj =  new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it works for me.

```
  if (!function_exists ("__autoload"))
    {

       function __autoload($classname)
       {
        require_once($class.".php");
       }
}
```